# Insert into a many-to-many table based on current row information

Tags: sql, many-to-many, bulkinsert, sequelpro

I have a many-to-many table of products and models ids. Is it possible to insert new rows if the ids match in another row?

Example Table:

```
| p_id | m_id |
+------+------+
|  A   |  2   |
|  A   |  3   |
|  B   |  1   |
|  B   |  2   |
|  C   |  1   |
```

SQL Script:

If any product is related to model 2, insert new row of that product and product 4.

The table would become:

```
| p_id | m_id |
+------+------+
|  A   |  2   |
|  A   |  3   |
|  A   |  4   |
|  B   |  1   |
|  B   |  2   |
|  B   |  4   |
|  C   |  1   |
```

I have to do this in SQL. More specifically, Sequel Pro.

Comment: My only etiquette feedback is to use the code format on your tables, and try not to add too chatty comments at the end.

Comment: I was about to answer your question but I didn't understood you want to insert where id='' doesn't makes sense can you give us more details??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not worked with Sequel Pro, so I don't know if I have the proper syntax, but perhaps I can give you the right logic.

In MySQL, you can use a select statement to insert new rows into a table. In your case, you want to insert new rows with the `p_id` of rows that have an `m_id` of 2. I would start by writing that query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p_id
FROM myTable
WHERE m_id = 2;
```

Then, you want each new row to have an `m_id` of 4. You can make that a constant in your select clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p_id, 4 AS m_id
FROM myTable
WHERE m_id = 2;
```

This will give you the rows you want to insert:

```
| p_id | m_id |
+------+------+
|  A   |  4   |
|  B   |  4   |
```

Now, to insert those rows, the syntax would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2) myQuery;
```

Here is what I used:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (p_id, m_id) SELECT DISTINCT p_id, 4 FROM myTable WHERE m_id = 2;
```

And here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d77dc/4) example.

Comment: Thank you! Two learns, making a constant in my select clause and SQL Fiddle.

Comment: SQL Fiddle is my best friend. It is also *very* helpful on this website, as it allows users to share table designs and queries to easily recreate issues and solve them. @IanDavis